# iOS Webrtc - Crash in RTCPeerConnectionFactory.VideoSourceWithCapturer

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, webrtc

I am using static library "libWebRTC.a" to create IOS App by binding it using Xamarin binding.

when I call `_factory.VideoSourceWithCapturer(capturer, mediaConstraints);` in this code the application crashes

```
      RTCVideoTrack CreateLocalVideoTrack()
    {
        RTCVideoTrack localVideoTrack = null;
        AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaType.Video, (bool isAccessGranted) =>
        {
            if (isAccessGranted)
            {
                String cameraID = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video).Length; i++)
                {
                    if (AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video)[i].Position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front)
                    {
                        cameraID = AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video)[i].LocalizedName;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //do something

                RTCVideoCapturer capturer = RTCVideoCapturer.CapturerWithDeviceName(cameraID);

                RTCMediaConstraints mediaConstraints = DefaultMediaStreamConstraints();
                RTCVideoSource videoSource = _factory.VideoSourceWithCapturer(capturer, mediaConstraints);
                localVideoTrack = _factory.VideoTrackWithID(@"ARDAMSv0", videoSource);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        });

        return localVideoTrack;
    }
```

and this is the message :

> Native stacktrace:
>
> critical:  0   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000100a18184 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 260
>
> critical:  1   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000100a23618 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 220
>
> critical:  2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000185a08348 _sigtramp + 52
>
> critical:  3   TestRTC                             0x000000010020b1fc _ZN7cricket13VideoCapturer15SetCaptureStateENS_12CaptureStateE + 52
>
> critical:  4   TestRTC                             0x0000000100214764 _ZN7cricket19WebRtcVideoCapturer5StartERKNS_11VideoFormatE + 1084
>
> critical:  5   TestRTC                             0x000000010020b190 _ZN7cricket13VideoCapturer14StartCapturingERKNS_11VideoFormatE + 52
>
> critical:  6   TestRTC                             0x0000000100202020 _ZN7cricket14CaptureManager26StartWithBestCaptureFormatEPNS_18VideoCapturerStateEPNS_13Vi
>   deoCapturerE + 204
>
> critical:  7   TestRTC                             0x0000000100201ea0 _ZN7cricket14CaptureManager17StartVideoCaptureEPNS_13VideoCapturerERKNS_11VideoFormatE + 196
>
> critical:  8   TestRTC                             0x000000010028c658 _ZN3rtc21FunctorMessageHandlerIbNS_14MethodFunctor2IN7cricket14CaptureManagerEMS3_FbPNS2_13VideoCapturerERKNS2_11VideoFormatEEbS5_S8_EEE9OnMessageEPNS_7MessageE + 24
>
> critical:  9   TestRTC                             0x00000001001f10c4 *ZN3rtc6Thread22ReceiveSendsFromThreadEPKS0* + 116
>
> critical:  10  TestRTC                             0x00000001001dc338 _ZN3rtc12MessageQueue3GetEPNS_7MessageEib + 156
>
> critical:  11  TestRTC                             0x00000001001f0df0 _ZN3rtc6Thread15ProcessMessagesEi + 108
>   TestRTC[634:2

Comment: Check if you have provided permissions in .plist to use camera and microphone.

Also if the above is done then try calling this on the main thread. :) Hope it helps .